# String to int java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string, int

I have java program which convert `String` to `int`, but the rang of String is `190520141618013381`(above the rang of `int`) when i convert this `int` the `java.lang.NumberFormatException:` is thrown

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
stringBuffer.append(format.format(date));
stringBuffer.append(demandCount);
int test_int = Integer.parseInt(stringBuffer.toString()); // exception has been fixed by putting 
                                //long abc_i = Long.parseLong(abc);
log.info("test_int: "+test_int);
```

my question is that compiler should throw `NumberOutOfRangException`(if this Exception is available in API) instead `java.lang.NumberFormatException:`, the format of number(`190520141618013381`) is right.

Comment: No, because that exception doesn't exist. In addition, `NumberFormatException` is correct, because the string isn't formatted *as an integer*

Comment: NumberFormatException is Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

Comment: i think `190520141618013381` value is in integer form, but not in integer rang

Comment: yes it is correct exception

Comment: Its not in the `int` form.

Comment: i meant to say 'int'('number' form)

Comment: This does not appear to be a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String `190520141618013381` is outside the range of an `int` but it also doesn't match the accepted format of an `int` because it is too long.

The compiler doesn't throw this error, it is thrown at runtime.

I believe it is correct to comply with the documentation for this method.

BTW Don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder ten years ago.

IMHO storing a date as an integer isn't a good idea in general.

---

A more efficient to get a unique id which contains the time in millis is to do something like this.

```
 private static final AtomicLong TS_COUNTER = new AtomicLong();

 public static long nextTimeStamp() {
      long time = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000;
      long curr = TS_COUNTER.get();
      if (curr < time && TS_COUNTER.compareAndSet(curr, time))
          return time;
      return TS_COUNTER.incrementAndGet();
 }
```

This will have the time-in-millis * 1000 plus a unique id.  This works fine if you average less than one million ids per second.

Comment: i am getting unique number this is my format `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyHHmmssSSS");` in last i concatenate my sql sequence number so that i get `190520141618013381`(but different every time)

Comment: @mohsinazeem Does your unique id need to have the time in it?

Comment: @Perter Currently it is not necessary, but i want to have long unique number in code so that i use `Date`

Comment: A timestamp is far from being a good way to generate unique identifiers. Try calling System.currentTimeMillis() in a loop, and see the result.

Comment: @mohsinazeem Try the above code.  You can get the time with `new Date(id/1000);`